GCS Objects Not Public Despite Setting allUsers with Storage Object Viewer Role
I followed the steps (via console) found here https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#managed-folders to make a folder (assets/) within my Google Cloud Bucket available on the public internet.
I have added the IAM policy to the folder so that allUsers have the Storage Object Viewer (roles/storage.objectViewer) role, as per the instructions. Permissions for assets/ folder showing that allUsers have the Storage Object Viewer permission.
The instructions in the linked page state that "Once public access has been granted, Copy URL appears for each applicable object in the public access column. You can click this button to get the public URL for the object." However, I am not seeing this, having opened the assets/ folder. Each object is showing as "Not public". See image

It's unhelpful to describe behavior without including evidence. Having followed this process myself, I know that it works and assume that Google's documentation is correct. So, the probability is that you're either missing a step or incorrectly following the instructions. However, you do not include evidence for any of this and so we cannot help. Please update your question with the specific steps that you followed (the commands; the output) and the steps that you're following to test.

Cheers champ, updated

Are you able to access objects that fall under your {bucket}/assets/ prefix without authenticating? I think the process works (the managed folder documentation is correct) but the documentation to access the public URLs is incorrect. You cannot use https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser but you can use https://storage.googleapis.com/{bucket}/assets/some.file

Here's my repro that demonstrates that it works:
BILLING="..."
PROJECT="..."
BUCKET="..."
FOLDER="..."
FILE="freddie.jpg"

gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}

gcloud billing projects link ${PROJECT} \
--billing-account=${BILLING}

gcloud storage buckets create gs://${BUCKET} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud storage buckets update gs://${BUCKET} \
--uniform-bucket-level-access

gcloud storage managed-folders create gs://${BUCKET}/${FOLDER}

gcloud storage managed-folders add-iam-policy-binding gs://${BUCKET}/${FOLDER} \
--member=allUsers \
--role=roles/storage.objectViewer

gcloud storage cp \
 ${FILE} \
 gs://${BUCKET}/${FOLDER}/${FILE}

Then:
curl \
--silent \
--get \
https://storage.googleapis.com/${BUCKET}/${FOLDER}/${FILE} \
--output /dev/null \
--write-out '%{response_code}'

Yields: 200
